# VBscript can't get SQL stored procedure results

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, vbscript

I created a proof-of-concept solution in one environment, but it isn't working in my test environment. My stored procedure works fine, as reported in SQL Management Studio and C#, and even in my development environment, but not in my test environment. Please help!

Here is some code to look at:

```
Function GetAutofillDatabaseInformation(docHandle, kwToCheck, autofillTableName, iDataType, aKeywordValues)
Dim i, adoParam, tempState, errDesc
GetAutofillDatabaseInformation = True
If Len(autofillTableName) = 0 Then autofillTableName = Null
On Error Resume Next
Set adoParam = adoCmd.CreateParameter("@Handle", adBigInt, adParamInput, , docHandle)
adoCmd.Parameters.Append(adoParam)
Set adoParam = adoCmd.CreateParameter("@KeyTypeNum", adBigInt, adParamInput, , kwToCheck)
adoCmd.Parameters.Append(adoParam)
Set adoParam = adoCmd.CreateParameter("@KeysetName", adChar, adParamInput, 200, autofillTableName)
adoCmd.Parameters.Append(adoParam)
Set adoParam = adoCmd.CreateParameter("@Datatype", adInteger, adParamOutput)
adoCmd.Parameters.Append(adoParam)
adoCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
adoCmd.CommandText = "usp_Check_Autofill_Value_Data"
adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoConn
Set adoRs = adoCmd.Execute
tempState = adoRs.State
errDesc = err.description
On Error Goto 0
ReDim aKeywordValues(0)
If Len(errDesc) = 0 Then
    i = 0
    Do until adoRs.EOF
        i = i + 1
        ReDim preserve aKeywordValues(i)
        aKeywordValues(i) = Trim(adoRs(0))
        adoRs.MoveNext
    Loop
    adoRs.Close
    iDataType = adoCmd.Parameters("@Datatype")
    If err.number <> 0 Then
        sErrMsg = "Cannot retrieve data information: " & err.description
        GetAutofillDatabaseInformation = False
    End If
Else
    sErrMsg = "No information retrieved from database for document " & docHandle & ", keyword " & kwToCheck & " and autofill table [" & autofillTableName & "]."
    GetAutofillDatabaseInformation = False
End If
End Function
```

I don't get any error message. The adoRs recordset object is always closed, and the @Datatype parameter doesn't get populated.

In my development environment, it all works fine. The development environment is Sql Server 2008 R2 SP1. The test environment is SP2 instead.

Is there some difference between SP1 and SP2 that would cause the ADO recordset not to be able to get any data?

Comment: Wow, what a convoluted approach. You realise you could have just used `adoRs.GetRows()` to generate an Array, it will be 2D but easier to work with then this. Not a fan of the error handling approach either.

Comment: In regard to the question, you likely have a provider issue *(is the connection string using the same provider?)*. You might also want to check `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is set on your stored procedure to avoid ADODB interpreting the record count as a closed recordset. You could test this by calling `Set adoRs = adoRs.NextRecordset` to see if the `ADODB.Command` contains another recordset that represents your actual query.

Comment: Thanks, @Lankymart. `SET NOCOUNT ON` is indeed set; I could post the stored procedure if necessary. The connection string differs in the server, username, and password, as they of course must. Sample: `adoConn.Open ("DSN=" & DSN & ";User ID=" & USERID & ";Password="& PASSWORD & ";")`

Comment: That connection string doesn't tell you much as you are using a DSN, if you have access to the DSN you want to check what provider is being used. For more on connection strings see http://connectionstrings.com.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you mean the driver, I did at first use a different driver, but created a new one that matches both environments. It is SQL Server Native Client 10.0, 32-bit platform.

Comment: Did you try the `NextRecordset` as a suggested test?

Comment: No, because the recordset object is closed when I get it back. From what I read about `NextRecordset`, that indicates no more recordsets exist.

Comment: If you call `Set adoRs = adoRs.NextRecordset` and the `adoRs.State` is still `adStateClosed` then you have no more record sets being returned, but you have to call it first to check.

Comment: _I don't get any error message._ That could be because you have `On Error Resume Next` in there. Comment it out and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ they have `errDesc = err.description` which would populate the variable with the last error description because they are using `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: @lLankymart Did not see that. Sorry.

Comment: FYI, I did end up discovering a way to make this work, but don't have an explanation for it. Instead of using parameters, I just used `EXEC usp_Check_Autofill_Value_Data` and filled in the parameters manually. Yes, subject to SQL injection, and I wouldn't want to do it that way, but at least it works. Some strange difference in the database, I guess.